# Group by in a dictionary<string, IList<string>>

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have a list of items "listItems", like this

```
Id Code Value
1  'a'  '1'
2  'a'  '2'
3  'b'  'x'
4  'b'  'y'
```

and want to obtain a dictionary,

```
'a' => '1', '2'
'b' => 'x', 'y'
```

I tried

`listItems.ToDictionary(x => x.Code, x => x.Value)`, but this returns a `Dictionary<string, string>`, I would like to have a `Dictionary<string, IList<string>>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can group by first

```
// gives Dictionary<string,IEnumerable<YourObject>>
listItems.GroupBy(x => x.Code).ToDictionary(x => x.Key);
```

you could project the values in the dictionary if need be:

```
// gives Dictionary<string,List<string>>
listItems.GroupBy(x => x.Code)
         .ToDictionary(
             x => x.Key, 
             x => x.Select(y => y.Value).ToList()
         );
```

Comment: using in async version, I have an error: "Unable to translate the given 'GroupBy' pattern. Call 'AsEnumerable' before 'GroupBy' to evaluate it client-side."